# Systemd resume script is executed only occasionally

Tags: systemd

I currently use Awesome WM without any desktop environment. This means that I have to get my keyboard and mouse settings there manually. I therefore wrote a shell script which makes a few calls to `setxkbmap` and `xinput`.

To execute it on resume, I wrote a systemd service file since Ubuntu 15.04 now uses systemd. It looks [like this](https://github.com/martin-ueding/playbooks/blob/master/roles/awesome-only/files/resume%40mu.service):

```
[Unit]
Description=User resume actions
After=suspend.target

[Service]
User=%I
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/mu-wakeup

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

The annoying thing is that this sometimes works, and sometimes does not work. I have not recognized the pattern.

I am not sure whether this interferes with `slock` which I use to lock the screen. `slock` is called by the [matching suspend service](https://github.com/martin-ueding/playbooks/blob/master/roles/awesome-only/files/suspend%40mu.service):

```
[Unit]
Description=Lock screen
Before=sleep.target

[Service]
User=%I
Type=simple
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/slock

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

I added a `sleep 5` into the `mu-wakeup` script. This did not help at all, so either it is not a race condition or the race condition cannot be hacked around with that.